# Modify download.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-server

I need to perform several actions exactly when a user clicks on the "Download a copy" link of the download.aspx page. To be specific, those actions consist on editing a PDF document "on the fly" whenever it's requested and bring the requester the edited version on the file. So in order to fulfill this requirement I decided that my best option was to modify the aforementioned download.aspx file.

My question is, where can I find that file? And the most important, how am I supposed to modify/override it to fit the requirements?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not "allowed" to edit standard (OOTB) pages of SharePoint.

The best (maybe only) doable approach is to create a "custom action" (i.e. a new button in the UI) and a custom layout (aka applicative) page.
The custom action targets your custom page, passing the document ID as a parameter. The code of the custom page does whatever you want.
Your users will then need to use your own new button instead of the standard "Download" one.

For your info: that page is most probably in the "SharePoint hive", i.e. `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\template\layouts` (replace `15` by `16` if you have SP2016, or by `14` if it's SP2010). However, you'll only have access to its aspx code, not its code-behind (C#), where most logic probably resides.

Comment: Hi Evariste and thanks for your repply. I've never done anything like this before, do you know about a sample project or article that explains in detail how to proceed?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using? Also, this will also require actual dev skills in any case.

Comment: SharePoint Server 2013. I would really appreciate some guidelines as I've never gone that far in SharePoint customization (although I've actually been involved in web dev projects).

Comment: As I wrote, it'd be an actual dev project. You can find something very close to what you need (in term of architecture: the implementation of the logic in the page has nothing to do) here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3a164c/deploying-custom-action-to-specific-lists-in-sharepoint-2010/.